# Fabric JS: Calculating line coordinates when the line moves in a group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/ogjvp30s/19/) I have one Fabric line and one rect. My objective is to get the line coordinates when it moves by itself or in a group with the rect.

If you only select the line and move it, the coordinates are displayed correctly (I took the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706847/fabricjs-line-coordinates-after-movement)).

But if you select both the line and the rect, the function does not work. I use `e.target._objects[0]` to get the line, that seems to be fine.

How to get the line coordinates when it's moved in the group?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926545/5045563) describes how object's left/top change when it is grouped. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351039/5045563) provides a great way to transform group-relative coordinates into absolute coordinates. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects inside the group are positioned in relation to the group and their coordinations are recalculated in relation to the center of the group. When it is moved in the group these factors should be considered.

Let's make a simplified example of only the top left coordinate. The absolute top left coordinate of the line is given by this formula:

```
'Absolute Line TL X' = 'Group top X left value' + (('Group width' / 2) + 'Line top left X value') 
'Absolute Line TL Y' = 'Group top Y left value' + (('Group height' / 2) + 'Line top left Y value')
```

Please check this simplified CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60416193-fabric-js-362-qpofr

```
canvas.on("object:moving", function(e) {
  var target;
  var coords;

  if (e.target._objects) {
    target = e.target._objects[0];
    coords = calcLineCoords(target, e.target);
  } else {
    target = e.target;
    coords = calcLineCoords(target);
  }

  caption.text = coords + "";
});

function calcLineCoords(line, groupContainer) {
  const { tl } = line.calcCoords();
  let coordsStart = tl;

  if (!!groupContainer) {
    const groupCoordinates = groupContainer.calcCoords();
    let groupCoordsStart = groupCoordinates.tl;

    var lineTopLeftX =
      groupCoordsStart.x + (groupContainer.get("width") / 2 + coordsStart.x);
    var lineTopLeftY =
      groupCoordsStart.y + (groupContainer.get("height") / 2 + coordsStart.y);

    return [lineTopLeftX, lineTopLeftY];
  } else {
    return [coordsStart.x, coordsStart.y];
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like calcCoords() is not available in 5.3 - any idea what the equivalent would be? I'll try looking in the source for 3.6

Comment: Wow easy fix just use calcOCoords() for 5.3